# Files copied to Windows share 'disappear' without error

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming

I'm copying files to a Windows network share on the same network over wifi with code like:

```
var dest = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\IANSDESKTOP\Shared\Stfc\Images");
var destFile = dest.File(file.Name);//File is just an extension method I made
file.CopyTo(destFile.FullName);
```

However sometimes the copy fails, as evidenced by `destFile` not being present, but it fails without any error message. I've tried some sanity checks in my code like:

```
destTemp.Refresh();
if (destTemp.Exists && destTemp.Length == file.Length)
//some error handling
```

Which has sometimes been triggered, and sometimes not, but still doesn't help solve the underlying issue.

Ignoring the possibility of a second application somewhere deleting the file, what could be causing this? Also, is there another way I can check for existence of the file? I'm considering adding a web server and API to check for files to remove the entire NFS aspect from the issue.

Comment: The problem could be in that extension method. What does it do? Could you add its code?

Comment: @Steve honestly it does nothing of interest: https://github.com/IanPNewson/NugetPackages/blob/master/INHelpers/ExtensionMethods/FilesystemExtensionMethods.cs#L52

Comment: Excluding for programming problems, it comes to mind only the activity of an antivirus, present on the PC that shares the folder, and does not like the file you are copying

Comment: @Steve I'll investigate that, thanks!